# perf trouble drawing 256 polygons on a sphere with three js

Tags: three.js, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

i'm facing a problem when i'm trying to insert on my sphere, 256 mesh using polygon previously generated and triangulated

1) Perf overwhelming, 5fps, don't understand really why, when i inspect the buffers using webgl inpspector i can see over 30k buffer stored ! i'm just drawing 256 polygon max...

2) the polygon aren't on the surface of my sphere but inside, they did not morph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00*0.05}));
```

before the loop. Since you are using the same material you only need to declare it once (pushed to the gpu once) not every loop iteration. So:

```
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00*0.05}));
for(i=0; i<mygeometry.length;i++){
  var object = new THREE.mesh(mygeometry[i],mat);
}
```

Comment: Click as useful answer? Trying to get my rep up hehe =]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you're creating 256 objects (buffers) instead of a single one. You should be adding all these polygons to a single geometry instead.